# Embed Prestashop product catalog on affiliate websites?

Tags: php, prestashop

What would be best to look into in order to develop a feature that would allow affiliate websites to display a product catalog from a Prestashop ecommerce website on their own site without resorting to an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Affiliate stores could use the [PrestaShop Web Service](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) to access the product catalog. The advantage of this method over the iframe is that the appearance of the product catalog can be easily customized. All you need is a small PHP script that syncs the catalog through the web service once a day and another to display the products.

There is a [PHP library for PrestaShop Webservices](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) that you can use.

Example:

```
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

$url = 'http://example.com';
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, 'EXAMPLEAPIKEY', false);

$opt['resource'] = 'products';
$opt['display'] = 'full';
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$productNodes = $xml->products->children();
foreach ($productNodes as $product) {
   //create REPLACE query from product data
}
```

Comment: Do you have any info on this you could provide besides that link?  Thanks!  I reviewed the link but honestly I'm not that familiar with Prestashop or PHP for that matter so I'm struggling.

Comment: @dcc I added an example. The implementation of the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) query depends on which product fields you want to display. You should run this script with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) once a day to sync the product catalog. You will need another script that selects the product data from the database and displays the products.